# how to change % so it reads horizontally rather than vertically on Gtsummary tables?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to reorientate my table so that the % ITN use is given by level, rather than % of observations in each level, for the ITN user and non-user group separately.

Basically, I would like the % to add up to 100 horizontally for rather than vertically

here is the code that I used to produce the table:

```
tbl_summary(pop.subtable1, by = ITN, missing = "no") %>%  
  modify_header(label = "Variable") %>% 
  modify_spanning_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**ITN USE**") %>% 
  italicize_labels() %>% bold_labels() %>% 
  add_overall() %>% 
  modify_caption("Table 3. Bed Net Use Amongst Population Characteristics")
```

I'm wondering if there's a line of code that I can insert that will manually do this?

here's what the table looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIbAH.png)

Comment: in `tbl_summary` there is an option to change percent to `percent = "row"`, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mike's comment, here is a reproducible example so others can see the difference between `percent = "column"` (default) and `percent = "row"` for [`tbl_summary()`](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_summary.html?q=percent).

> **percent** Indicates the type of percentage to return. Must be one of "column", "row", or "cell". Default is "column".

```
library(gtsummary)
data(trial)

## default (column)
trial %>%
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    percent = "column",
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    missing = "no"
  )
```

[image]

```
## row
trial %>%
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    percent = "row",
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    missing = "no"
  )
```

[image]